# Syncing application servers with changes in MongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, synchronization, real-time

I have a source app which performs updates on a mongo collection frequently. And there are different agent app servers which needs to load the collection in memory and ensure that it is in sync with the database and here are different implementation strategies which I am considering

**Strategy 1**

Source app updates the database 
    -> Agent app servers listen for changes for entire mongodb collection using mongo change stream(tailable cursors) and load them

Cons
 - Load on database

**Strategy 2**

Source app updates redis(pass through cache) with the collection and then updates the database -> Collection update event is published to consul
- > Agent App servers watch the event on consul
On reception of event -> Loads the collection from redis to in-memory

Can someone help me decide which is the best strategy to go about achieving this ?

*Input dataset*

- Mongo collection size is few MBs and ever growing
- Updates from source app to the collection is frequent like 100 requests per day

Comment: If your load is 100 requests per day, then go with strategy 1. DB load is not going to be a problem for you. If you want to check another method see: https://debezium.io/

Comment: Agent app servers are large in number say 20 and it can scale to 50-100s. Do you see the first approach work in this case ?

Comment: Is it is a good model for apps to listen directly on database ? I doubt whether it is a scalable approach